# ClassNotFound in rest services (spring mvc) but it's there in a static main

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a maven web app developed using spring-mvc. I am trying to use an external jar that I have put in the classpath but at runtime I am getting a ClassNotFoundException when I invoke a REST service that uses this class.

If I run a static main (outside of the tomcat server) everything works fine.

Any hint?

Comment: Check if the jar is really on the classpath. Also check, if the external jar file is there only once, because it can happen, that there are two external jar files of different versions, everyone containing a different implementation of the class.

Comment: Yes, the jar is there only once and is in the classpath

Comment: I was able to make it work buy copying the jars on lib folder in tomcat. The only problem now is that, even though I have my log4j.properties set to ERROR, I got DEBUG. it's like one of the jars I copied on the lib folder in tomcat has priority higher than mine. Any solution?

Comment: Does it exists in your WEB-INF/Lib directory?

Comment: the log4j.properties?